# Output from Vertex Shader is wrong when attempting Matrix Translation in DirectX C++

Tags: directx, matrix-multiplication, hlsl

I'm attempting to have a 3D object move position via Matrix Translation. I understand how Matrix multiplication works, but I'm using a graphics framework provided for me by my University, so it's possible something else is happening in the shader that I dont fully understand. The shader code is as follows:

```
PixelInputType output;
float4 worldPosition;


// Change the position vector to be 4 units for proper matrix calculations.
input.position.w = 1.0f;

// Rotate model and move to correct position
input.position = mul(input.position, rotate);
input.position = mul(input.position, modelPosition);

// Calculate the position of the vertex against the world, view, and projection matrices.
output.position = mul(input.position, worldMatrix);
output.position = mul(output.position, viewMatrix);
output.position = mul(output.position, projectionMatrix);

// Store the texture coordinates for the pixel shader.
output.tex = input.tex;

// Calculate the normal vector against the world matrix only.
output.normal = mul(input.normal, (float3x3)worldMatrix);

// Normalize the normal vector.
output.normal = normalize(output.normal);

// Calculate the position of the vertex in the world.
worldPosition = mul(input.position, viewMatrix);

// Determine the viewing direction based on the position of the camera and the position of the vertex in the world.
output.viewDirection = cameraPosition.xyz - worldPosition.xyz;

// Normalize the viewing direction vector.
output.viewDirection = normalize(output.viewDirection);

return output;
```

When I attempt to use this, it looks like the following [jagged chaos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZuIw.png)

Oddly enough, it worked fine when I was simply passing in a Vector3 and doing this before:

```
 PixelInputType output;
float4 worldPosition;


// Change the position vector to be 4 units for proper matrix calculations.
input.position.w = 1.0f;

// Calculate the position of the vertex against the world, view, and projection matrices.
output.position = mul(input.position, worldMatrix);
output.position = mul(output.position, rotate);
output.position = mul(output.position, viewMatrix);
output.position = mul(output.position, projectionMatrix);

output.position.x = output.position.x + modelPosition.x;
output.position.y = output.position.y + modelPosition.y;
output.position.z = output.position.z + modelPosition.z;

// Store the texture coordinates for the pixel shader.
output.tex = input.tex;

// Calculate the normal vector against the world matrix only.
output.normal = mul(input.normal, (float3x3)worldMatrix);

// Normalize the normal vector.
output.normal = normalize(output.normal);

// Calculate the position of the vertex in the world.
worldPosition = mul(input.position, viewMatrix);

// Determine the viewing direction based on the position of the camera and the position of the vertex in the world.
output.viewDirection = cameraPosition.xyz - worldPosition.xyz;

// Normalize the viewing direction vector.
output.viewDirection = normalize(output.viewDirection);

return output;
```

So I'm not entirely sure where I'm going wrong. All the values are definitely being passed into the shader correctly.

Comment: This usually means your matrices have bogus values in the bottom row (column-major) or right column (row-major) Try transposing your matrices or do mul (M,v) instead of mul(v, M)

Comment: Ah! StarShine, you were exactly right. I should have been doing 'input.position = mul(modelPosition, input.position);' rather than ' input.position = mul(input.position, modelPosition);'

Thanks! I don't know how to mark your answer as correct, otherwise I would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are using column-major instead of row-major matrices, in which case all your matrices are transposed. That means that the translation offset which would normally be in the last column (column-major) would instead be on the bottom row. The effect of having values other than 0 0 0 1 in the last row is that your matrix is no longer Cartesian, and instead you end up with rotations and scaling factors, which is what gives the pinch effects in your output.

The solution is to either transpose your matrices before multiplication, or for vector/matrix multiplication you can pre-multiply instead of post-multiply (and vice-versa)  with the vertex. [Here](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/mathematics-physics-for-computer-graphics/geometry/row-major-vs-column-major-vector) is a pretty nice explanation.

In glsl (OpenGL) you would use column major matrices and write v' = Mcm * v I'm not regularly using DirectX but it uses row-major matrices in code, while hlsl uses column-major matrices. It is common to transpose your matrices when you pass them on into the shader.

Comment: The HLSL compiler defaults to using column-major, while most Direct3D programming is row-major. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509634.aspx#Matrix_Ordering). This is controlled by the ``/Zpc`` and ``/Zpr`` switches on ``FXC.EXE`` and the ``D3DCOMPILE_PACK_MATRIX_ROW_MAJOR`` vs. ``D3DCOMPILE_PACK_MATRIX_COLUMN_MAJOR`` flags for the D3DCompile API. Typically Direct3D applications leave it as the default, and just transpose the matrix as they write it into the constant buffer.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn ah thanks for clearing that up. Also I believe the DirectX driver internally reconverts back to column major should you choose to go with /Zpr.